# How do I send a request after being blocked in Instagram

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, request, instagram

I'm trying to make a tool that log in into Instagram account and do some jobs using requests library, but after about 7-10 attempts I got banned I think, and I got this reply:
`{"message":"Please wait a few minutes before you try again.","status":"fail"}`


I tried many things to unban me, I used a proxy, and I changed the user agent, but none of them worked and the ban still exists.

```
from uuid import uuid4
import requests

r = requests.Session()
def check(username, password):
    proxies = { "https": "https://proxy:port" }
    url = 'https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/'
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Instagram 113.0.0.39.122 Android (24/5.0; 515dpi; 1440x2416; huawei/google; Nexus 6P; angler; angler; en_US)', 'Accept':'*/*', 'Cookie':'missing', 'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate', 'Accept-Language':'en-US', 'X-IG-Capabilities':'3brTvw==', 'X-IG-Connection-Type':'WIFI', 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Host':'i.instagram.com'}
    uid = str(uuid4())
    data = {'uuid':uid, 'password':password, 'username':username, 'device_id':uid, 'from_reg':'false', '_csrftoken':'missing', 'login_attempt_countn':'0'}
    req_login = r.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, allow_redirects=True, proxies=proxies)

    print (req_login.text)

check("user", "password")
```

This is the code, but as I said before, nothing changes, the ban is there for now, but if I wait two or three days and try again, it works, and it blocks me again after number of attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need permissions to use instagram API and the limit is very strict.

You can read more and apply for permissions here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

The reason why changing proxies / user-agent doesn't work is because the ban is tied to your account.

You'd be better off using an automation script with [Frida](https://github.com/frida/frida) that interacts with the Instagram app itself, rather than trying to bypass the API limit with only one account.